# How to parse collection like input in a SQL procedure called from Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory pipeline that has a lookup activity that calls a stored procedure and passes in a collection which is the child item from the previous activity `@activity('EnumNewFiles').output.childitems`. It is a list of file names from a storage service.

I am recording the procedure input in the database. A representation of an object is being stored; `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]`. Naively I expected the collection to be serialized as JSON. What i would like `[{"name": "xyz", "type": "File"}, ...]`. I cannot see any built-in data factory functions that can serialize the object for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the collection to JSON String and parse it in SQL Server. Please try this expression:
`@{activity('EnumNewFiles').output.childitems}` or`@string(activity('EnumNewFiles').output.childItems)`.